# R variable usage with ~

Tags: r

When I look at documentation like:

```
plot_ly(mpg, x = ~cty, y = ~hwy, z = ~cyl) %>%
  add_markers(color = ~cyl)
```

I wonder what the `~` is doing. The mpg data set has variables city, etc so what is wrong with using `city` instead of `~city` ?

When should I add `~` in front of variable names?

Answer (score 2):

According to `?plot_ly`

> A formula must always be used when referencing column name(s) in data (e.g. plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt)). Formulas are optional when supplying values directly, but they do help inform default axis/scale titles (e.g., plot_ly(x = mtcars$wt) vs plot_ly(x = ~mtcars$wt))

---

In the context of `plot_ly`, it is taking inputs as formula when unquoted columns are provided or can directly give the value of the column by extracting the column (`mtcars$wt` or `mtcars[["wt"]]` or `mtcars[, "wt"]`